# How to associate existing editor/classifier with a new file extension?

Tags: visual-studio, mef, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I would like to my Visual Studio extension to have C# syntax highlighting for a file with .customExt. The desirable effect is easily achievable form VS UI : `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension`, but how to achieve similar effect from extension level?
Is it possible to get existing VS csharp classifier?
Or maybe there is a way to associate .customExt to existing Microsoft Visual C# editor?

I have tried:

```
[Export]
[FileExtension(".customExt")]
[ContentType("CSharp")]
internal static FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition hiddenFileExtensionDefinition;
```

but it obviously does not work as expected.

Comment: Maybe you could refer to this sample about custom file type: [https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Editor_With_Toolbox](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Editor_With_Toolbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on how to associate a custom file type with the existing editor here:

[New extension: CSS Is Less](https://web.archive.org/web/20150104052736/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahric/archive/2010/03/01/new-extension-css-is-less.aspx)

It is very simple, it only requires adding .pkgdef file to VSIX project:

```
[$RootKey$\Languages\File Extensions\.customExt]
@="{694dd9b6-b865-4c5b-ad85-86356e9c88dc}"

[$RootKey$\Editors\{08467b34-b90f-4d91-bdca-eb8c8cf3033a}\Extensions]
"customExt"=dword:00000027
```

The file should have the following properties set:

- Copy to Output Directory: Copy always
- Include in VSIX: True